# spring jdbctemplate.query method gives me this exception invalid argument java.io Not Serializable exception

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate, notserializableexception

[enter image description here][1]
this is my code where i got java.ioNotSerializabale Exception
when i run below query i got this exception

> java.io.NotSerializableException

my pojo class is here 
public class ProjectHelper implements Serializable {

```
private String name;
private String description;
private String company;
private String category;
private List<UserRegister> usersRegisterList;

private String startDate;
```

And this is my DaoImpl method where i got error "java.io.NotSerializableException"

```
@Override
public GenericModal getProjects(User email) throws SQLException {

    String sql = "select p.project_name, p.project_description, p.company,                      p.start_date, p.end_date, " +
            "p.category f.task, f.milestones, f.billing, f.time_log, f.messages, f.features_id, f.files, u.firstName" +
            "u.lastname, u.email" +
            " from project as p" +
            "join userprojectrelation as upr" +
            "on p.project_id=upr.project_id " +
            "join users as u" +
            "on u.UserId=upr.user_id" +
            "join features as f " +
            "on f.project_id=p.project_id" +
            "where u.email=?";
    int status = 0;
    GenericModal genericModal=new GenericModal();

    try {
        List<ProjectHelper> projectHelper=jdbcTemplate.query(sql,new Object[]{email},new ProjectHelperMapper());
        if (projectHelper.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            genericModal.setObject(projectHelper);
        }
       // return genericModal;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        genericModal.setException(ex.getMessage());
    }

    return genericModal;
}
```

Comment: Please use Java standard spacing for readability. Makes it easier for us, the guys and galls that want to help you, to actually help you.

Comment: @Flummox plz try to solve the question rather than criticizing i already used spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably UserRegister that isn't Serializable. If you want to serialize a class, all of it's components (fields) must also be serializable, unless you implement custom serialization methods or mark the fields as transient.

Comment: I already made ProjectHelper class serilizable which cover all pojos

Comment: Also my guess. Also the List interface is not serializable, but many implementations are, however this is not an issue as serialization is only checked runtime.

Comment: @UdaibKhan it is not enough to make ProjectHelper  Serializable, every type it references (that is not transient) must be serializable as well.

Comment: @KlausGroenbaek i made all its refernces serializable but error is same

Comment: Like I said in the answer, you can't just mark the class as Serializable. You must also make all components serializable, or manually do the serialization yourself. Otherwise, how is the auto-serialization code supposed to know how to serialize UserRegister?

Comment: We need to see the code. How did you make it serializable?

Comment: public class ProjectHelper implements Serializable {

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String company;
    private String category;
    private List<UserRegister> usersRegisterList;

    private String startDate;
    private String endDate;


    private String task;
    private String mileStones;
    private String billing;
    private String files;
    private String timeLog;
    private String message;

}

Comment: sorry this is my first time i am posting questions in stackover flow so i making mistakes while posting

Comment: That's only ProjectHelper. That's not the problem. The problem is in your UserRegister class. That's the code we need to see.

Comment: public class UserRegister implements Serializable {
    private  int userId;
    private String firstName;


    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String regPassword;
    private String companyName;
    private String siteAddress;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String role;
    private String message;

    public  UserRegister(){}


    public String getRole() {return role;}

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

Comment: @JeremyGurr the above code is my UserRegister modal

Comment: Hmm... that should be fine since it only consists of Strings, and an int.

Comment: Then the next potential trouble spot would be what exactly the class of projectHelper is. It's some kind of List. If you can log that or debug it, and tell us the exact class, it might lead to a solution.

Comment: @JeremyGurr sorry i did'nt get it what you are saying? plz explain it

Comment: why is it serializable in the first place? it looks like ProjectHelper holds data from a database. Serialization is typically used for transport and sometimes persistence. If they are already in the DB, it's probably not persistence, if it is transport I recommend a human readable format like JSON, rather than Java's binary serialization.

Comment: @KlausGroenbaek ProojectHelper is getting data from bootstrap modal and then passing data to multiple pojos for futher persistence process and also ProjectHelper is used here for holding data from DB

Comment: In this line of code:  genericModal.setObject(projectHelper);  we need to know the exact class of projectHelper. Is it an ArrayList, or something else? If it's something that's not serializable, then that's your problem.

Comment: @JeremyGurr GenericModal is simple class used for handling exception and holding other related data i am sharing "GenericModal" class below .....                                                                                          public class GenericModal{
    private String exception;
    private List<Object> list;
    private Object object;
    private int status;

    //getters and setters

Comment: i m returning json object  form spring controllerr i have web service which is returning all projects to user . @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/projects", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
     public ProjectHelper  getProjects(Model model, HttpSession session) throws SQLException {

        User user = (User) session.getAttribute("LOGGEDIN_USER");
        GenericModal genericModal = projectService.getProjects(user);
        ProjectHelper projectHelper = (ProjectHelper) genericModal.getObject();
        return projectHelper;
    }